# Caught KeyError while rendering: u'minutes'

Tags: django, celery

when I try to acced to /admin/djcelery/taskstate/ in django app it return this error
 how can I solve this error

```
  Template error:
  In template c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin   \change_list.html, error at line 95
  Caught KeyError while rendering: u'minutes'
  85 :         {% endif %}
  86 :       {% endblock %}
  87 :       
  88 :       <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if   cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>{% csrf_token %}

  89 :       {% if cl.formset %}
  90 :         {{ cl.formset.management_form }}
  91 :       {% endif %}
  92 : 
  93 :       {% block result_list %}
  94 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{%   admin_actions %}{% endif %}
```

error line 95 !!!

```
  95 :            {% result_list cl %} 

  96 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}

  97 :       {% endblock %}
  98 :       {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
  99 :       </form>
  100 :     </div>

  101 :   </div>

  102 : {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This unicode error is very common in Django. You need to either convert into string what you are sending from back-end or parse it in the front end.
In backend do `str(x)` of the value that is getting the error in front end. i.e in you case `minutes`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a bug in the pypi version that is already fixed in github.
In the current pypi package (format is in humanize.py in line 64):

```
return ungettext(
    _('{minutes} minute ago'),
    _('{minutes} minutes ago'), minutes
).format(minutes)
```

This doesn't work, it would have to be {0} instead of {minutes}.
In the master branch in github that's already fixed:

```
return ungettext(
    _('{minutes} minute ago'),
    _('{minutes} minutes ago'), minutes
).format(minutes=minutes)
```

I would suggest just using the github version, you can pip install the most current commit like this:

```
pip install -e "git+git://github.com/celery/django-celery.git@b6eeb8952594a7f8073901db613801f2ac544cd7#egg=django-celery"
```

If you leave the commit id out, it will always install the current head, but it's safer to use a specific commit in case there are breaking changes.